# Pequeño problema con setInterval y clearInterval (javascript)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

**El problema es que la primera vez funciona perfecto, pero al pararlo y encenderlo de nuevo... el boton de parar ya no para el bucle y se repite constantemente**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    function intervalo (){
        
        var iniciar = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('Este mensaje se mostrara cada 4 segundos') 
      
        },4000);
      
       return iniciar;
    };

    var iniciar = intervalo();
    var start = document.getElementById('start');
    var stop = document.getElementById('parar');

    stop.addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log('stop timer');
        clearInterval(iniciar);
        
    });

    start.addEventListener('click',function(){
          console.log('run timer');
          intervalo();
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="start" >Comenzar</button><br><br>
<button id="parar">Parar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Así es como lo haría yo:
`iniciar` tendría que ser false al principio. Y después de clearInterval también.
Cuando llamas el `intervalo()` guardalo  siempre en la variable `iniciar`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var iniciar = false;
  var start = document.getElementById("start");
  var stop = document.getElementById("parar");

  function intervalo() {
    var iniciar = setInterval(function() {
      console.log("Este mensaje se mostrara cada 4 segundos");
    }, 4000);
    return iniciar;
  }

  stop.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("stop timer");
    clearInterval(iniciar);
    iniciar = false;
  });

  start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("run timer");
    iniciar = intervalo();
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="start" >Comenzar</button><br><br>
<button id="parar">Parar</button>
```